# Can I hold a condition in NMaximize/NMinimize?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, hold

I'd like to use `NMaximize`/`NMinimize` with the condition `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[someMatrix[variables]]`.

However, `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ` always returns `False` unless the matrix is positive for all complex values of the variables (which is not my case, but that's why I need to implement the condition in the first place!).

How can I have MMA first evaluate the matrix and only then check if it's positive semidefinite? At the moment I'm using the condition

```
Min@Eigenvalues[myMatrix[variables]] >= 0
```

But it's sooo slow...

EDIT
I'm supplying an example:

```
 NMinimize[{a, PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[{{1,0},{0,a}}]},a]
```

The solution of this problem is a = 0, but MMA cannot enforce the condition.

Comment: It would really help if you could share a matrix to play with, but as a blind suggestion, try defining `psQ[m_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] :=  PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[m]` and use `psQ[yourmatrix]` within your `NMaximize`. The `NumericQ` condition will prevent evaluation until the matrix elements are given numerical values.

Comment: Nice idea, but NMaximize still complains that the constraint is not valid (this time because it returns unevaluated, as the initial matrix is not numerical).
You can try with any matrix, try with `{{1,0},{0,a}}`.

Comment: Can you maybe give a tiny example? Also maybe try SetAttributes[psQ, HoldAll]; psQ[m_] := PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[m];

Comment: As Searke said, an example for us to play with would do wonders here.

Comment: I am not at all sure that positive semidefiniteness is a valid constraint for `NMinimize`. Constraints, for it, are limited to things that can be enforced using KKT conditions.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I think you are correct. The error message seems to indicate that constraints must be expressions of (in)equality involving the variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea would be to use an explicit penalty function.  (I couldn't get it to work with the `"PenaltyFunction"` option.)

```
npsQ[m_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Boole@Not@PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[m];

mat = {{1, 0}, {0, a}};
NMinimize[a (1 - 2 npsQ[mat]), a]
(*  {1.8919*10^-9, {a -> -1.8919*10^-9}}  *)

Plot[{a (1 - 2 npsQ[mat])}, {a, -1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example is probably more typical:

```
mat = {{1, -1}, {-1, a}};
NMinimize[a - 2 a npsQ[mat], a]
(*  {-1., {a -> 1.}}  *)

Plot[{a (1 - 2 npsQ[mat])}, {a, -1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the minimum value is not the value of `a`, but `a` is available from the last element of the return value of `NMinimize`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! Unfortunately, it is still very slow in comparison to what a colleague showed me using python and an SVD solver. That's an important functionality that MMA still lacks...

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to take the Cholesky decomposition of the matrix, and use the squares of the diagonal elements (which should be nonnegative) as the constraints:

```
g = CholeskyDecomposition[{{1, 0}, {0, a}}];
NMinimize[{a, And @@ Thread[Diagonal[g]^2 >= 0]}, a]
   {0., {a -> 0.}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Oleksandr pointed out as well, you may not be able to use your constraint as stated. Your alternative expressed as an inequality should actually be quite function, if you can calculate the eigenvalues of your target matrix symbolically in a reasonable time.

You first obtain a symbolic expression for your eigenvalues, by running Eigenvalues once only, and store it away, perhaps `Simplify`ing it if need be. You then try to minimize the minimum eigenvalue. In your simple case, some constraint on the value of a also needs to be imposed to obtain a unique solution, so I chose to impose that a be positive or zero.

```
eigen = Eigenvalues[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, a}}];
NMinimize[{Min@eigen, a >= 0}, a]

(* {0., {a -> 0.}} *)
```

Comment: Oh, yes of course this would be my first choice if I could actually compute the eigenvalues of my matrix! But the actually matrix is 16x16 and pretty ugly, with many variables (not just `a`). The example I posted is a much much simplified one.